# Update data based on serial number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm that enables users to enter data into a worksheet.

A serial number is created for each row of data based on 2 ComboBox selection and `0001` at the end.

For example, `MAPR0001` where `MA` comes from a ComboBox and `PR` from another one and at the end `0001` is added and is incremented for another selection of `MA` and `PR`. (`MAPR0002`)

Then I have a second UserForm that should allow me to update my database.
Upon selection of a serial number from a ComboBox the second UserForm pulls back the data from the worksheet to some TextBoxes.
Till here everything works fine.

But I fail to add data to a specific serial number.

My code for the command button:

```
Private sub Commandbuttonclick ()
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Request No. Can Not be Blank", vbExclamation, "Request No."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    requestno = Me.ComboBox1.Value
    Sheets("DASHBOARD").Select

    Dim rowselect As Double
    rowselect = Me.combobox1.Value
    rowselect = rowselect + 1
    Rows(rowselect).Select

    Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.TextBox2.Value
    Cells(rowselect, 4) = Me.TextBox3.Value
```

Comment: Looking good to me, I'm just the wrong person to answer it ;)

Comment: Not looking good to me ;) ① [Avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) ② `Dim rowselect As Double` must be `Dim rowselect As Long`

Comment: Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to find your serial number that you want to update. `Match` returns the row number that you could use instead of `rowselect` to write your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to find your serial number that you want to update. `Match` returns the row number that you could use instead of `rowselect` to write your data.

For example something like this:

```
Dim MySerial As String
MySerial = "MAPR0001" 'adjust to your needs

Dim MyLookupRange As Range
Set MyLookupRange = Sheets("DASHBOARD").Range("A:A") 'adjust to where your serials are

Dim RowToUpdate As Long
On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if serial not found
RowToUpdate = WorksheetFunction.Match(MySerial, MyLookupRange, 0)
On Error Goto 0 'always re-enable error reporting!

If RowToUpdate > 0 Then
    'serial found, update here eg …
    'Sheets("DASHBOARD").Cells(RowToUpdate, 2) = Me.TextBox1.Value
Else
    MsgBox "Serial " & MySerial & " was not found."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  Here is one option for you to try.

```
'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Sub ImportDataFromExcel()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Coding\Integrating Access and Excel and SQL Server\Access & Excel & SQL Server\" & _
        "EXCEL AND ACCESS AND SQL SERVER\Excel & Access\Select, Insert, Update & Delete\Northwind.mdb"
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open strConn

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
        lastcolumn = .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
    End With

        'therow = 1

        For i = 2 To lastrow
            'r = rng.Row
            'If r > 1 Then
                strSQL = "UPDATE PersonInformation SET " & _
                    "FName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "LName='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Address='" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value & "', " & _
                    "Age=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value & " WHERE " & _
                    "ID=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
                conn.Execute strSQL
            'End If
            'r = r + 1
        Next i


    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is for illustration purposes only.  Please change to suit your specific needs.